# VB.net (Dev Express XtraReport)

Tags: vb.net, xtrareport

Developing a VB.net Winform project with Dev ExpresDataSSols. After declaringan open SQL connection, SQL command /SqlGridAdapter, I assigned a DataTable to a Grid Control tool. The GridView from my Grid Control was passed to a Dev Express XtraReport object.  The XtraReport successfully showed the DataTable from the GridControl's  GridView. - I then attempted to add a Dev Express CalculatedField to my XtraReport, but the CalculatedField is not displayed in the XtraReport. Any ideas on how to correct this code?  Thanks!

```
Dim rep As XtraReport = New XtraReport( )
rep = ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(rep, GridView1)

Dim calcField As New CalculatedField( )
rep.CalculatedFields.Add(calcField)

calcField.Data Source=rep.DataSource
calcField.DataMember=rep.DataMember
calcField.FieldType=FieldType.Int32
calcField.Name="Total"
calcField.Expression="SUM([Field])"

rep.ShowPreview()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the field that you want to sum is named Field?
Are you sure [to have value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q528535/calculated-field-not-showing-on-report) in the database for that field?

based on the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/7052/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shaping-Report-Data/Using-Calculated-Fields/Creating-a-Calculated-Field-Runtime-Sample) it seem ok.

sorry i can't comment because i'haven't enought reputation..

Comment: gsimo83 - Yes the DataTable field is correct. I was not able to find missing property for CalculatedField() object that would be causing it not to appear in the final XtraReport.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've added a calculated field to a report, but have not created a label or table cell that's bound to the calculated field. This is demonstrated in the [Creating a Calculated Field (Runtime Sample)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/7052/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shaping-Report-Data/Using-Calculated-Fields/Creating-a-Calculated-Field-Runtime-Sample) topic:

```
/ Bind a label's Text property to the calculated field 
// depending on the report's data binding mode.
if (Settings.Default.UserDesignerOptions.DataBindingMode == DataBindingMode.Bindings)
    report.FindControl("xrlabel3", true).DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "Products.myField", "{0:c2}");
else report.FindControl("xrlabel3", true).ExpressionBindings.Add(
    new ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "FormatString('{0:c2}', [myField])"));
```